# Join two tables on multiple conditions - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to join two tables based on some conditions. The src tale in my daily input. I need to  join the src table with the mstr table based on some criteria which is as below.

1. If I get a join between the two tables by memberid, fname and lname then I need to take the dob from the mstr table.
2. If I do not get a matching criteria on the above basis then I need to join just by member id and then take the dob. If there are multiple records available in the mstr by member id then I need to pick that record which has the older of the dob.
3. If I do not get a match by memberid also then the need to randomly create a fname which would be xx+5random numbers, lname would be ZZ+5andom numbers and dob as today's date - 110 years.

This is what I have tried which would help you expedite the solution. I am providing the sample data for both the tables

```sql
declare @src table (memberids int, fnames varchar(25), lnames varchar(25));
insert into @src values
(1, 'Ankit','Bansal'),
(2, 'Dinesh','Bansal'),
(3, 'Sushil','Dania'),
(4, '',''),
(5, Null ,Null),
(10,Null,Null)

select * from @src
```

```sql
declare @mstr table (memberid int, fname varchar(25), lname varchar(25),dob date);
insert into @mstr values
(1, 'Ankit','Bansal','2010-06-24'),
(2, 'Dinesh','Bansal','2009-06-24'),
(3, 'Sushil','Dania','2000-06-24'),
(4, 'Sunil','Wadh','2011-06-24'),
(5, 'Suresh','Bansal','2000-06-24'),
(5, 'Animesh','Bajaj','2001-06-24'),
(6, 'Dhiresh','Jain','2001-06-24');


select * from @mstr;
```

This is the query that I have written.

```sql
 select  memberids, fnames, lnames, a.dob
 from @src
 outer apply
  (select dob
         from @mstr where memberids = memberid and fnames = fname 
         and lnames = lname) a ;
```

The current result that I am getting is

```
memberids   fnames  lnames  dob
1   Ankit   Bansal  2010-06-24
2   Dinesh  Bansal  2009-06-24
3   Sushil  Dania   2000-06-24
4           NULL
5   NULL    NULL    NULL
10  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

However the output should look like below

```
memberids   fnames  lnames  dob
1   Ankit   Bansal  24-06-2010
2   Dinesh  Bansal  24-06-2009
3   Sushil  Dania   24-06-2000
4   Sunil   Wadh    24-06-2011
5   Suresh  Bansal  24-06-2000
10  XX12345 ZZ123456    Today's Date - 110 years
```

Comment: why your master table has 2 reference for MemberID = 5? Is that real data? or by mistake?

Comment: Yes that is real data. There can be two members of a family in one Member ID. So one member id can have two different names.

Comment: Which fname and lname you required from those 2 rows?

Comment: Please find below which has been mentioned above also.                                 If I do not get a matching criteria on the above basis then I need to join just by member id and then take the dob. If there are multiple records available in the mstr by member id then I need to pick that record which has the older of the dob

Comment: Is it right to have records without unique member id? You said it as master table, but no primary key column in that !!

Comment: Query added in the answer section

Comment: How could you assume members can have same member I'd even you consider DOB? Every member of a family should have unique id. Please consider normalization concept.

Comment: There is much more business rules and I have only asked the part where I was having a challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following will do (tested on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2756e/8)):

```
SELECT @src.memberids
     , CASE WHEN a.memberid IS NOT NULL THEN @src.fnames
            WHEN b.memberid IS NOT NULL THEN b.fname
            ELSE 'XX' + FORMAT(ABS(CAST(CHECKSUM(NewId()) AS BIGINT)) % 100000, '00000')
       END AS fnames
     , CASE WHEN a.memberid IS NOT NULL THEN @src.lnames
            WHEN b.memberid IS NOT NULL THEN b.lname
            ELSE 'ZZ' + FORMAT(ABS(CAST(CHECKSUM(NewId()) AS BIGINT)) % 100000, '00000')
       END AS lnames
     , CASE WHEN a.memberid IS NOT NULL THEN a.dob
            WHEN b.memberid IS NOT NULL THEN b.dob
            ELSE DATEADD(year, -110, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
       END AS dob
  FROM @src
  LEFT JOIN @mstr a ON a.memberid = @src.memberids
                   AND a.fname = @src.fnames
                   AND a.lname = @src.lnames
  OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 1 b.memberid, b.fname, b.lname, b.dob
       FROM @mstr b
      WHERE b.memberid = @src.memberids
      ORDER BY b.dob
  ) b
```

Comment: Loosing out the last row in the src i.e. the row where memberids is 10

Comment: @Sunil Changed `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY` fixed that.

Comment: Thanks. It did. I am more of an ETL person so find it difficult to do the same using SQL as I our client want's us to do things by SQL and use ETL tool more as a place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query. This should work but I must say that there are flaw in table design. If this is the requirement, consider the following query. But if you have scope, you can rethink to redesign your table first.

```
declare @src table (memberids int, fnames varchar(25), lnames varchar(25));
insert into @src values
(1, 'Ankit','Bansal'),
(2, 'Dinesh','Bansal'),
(3, 'Sushil','Dania'),
(4, '',''),
(5, Null ,Null),
(10,Null,Null)

declare @mstr table (memberid int, fname varchar(25), lname varchar(25),dob date);
insert into @mstr values
(1, 'Ankit','Bansal','2010-06-24'),
(2, 'Dinesh','Bansal','2009-06-24'),
(3, 'Sushil','Dania','2000-06-24'),
(4, 'Sunil','Wadh','2011-06-24'),
(5, 'Suresh','Bansal','2000-06-24'),
(5, 'Animesh','Bajaj','2001-06-24'),
(6, 'Dhiresh','Jain','2001-06-24');

SELECT M.memberid,M.fname,M.lname,M.dob
FROM (
    SELECT M.memberid, MIN(M.dob) dob
    FROM @src S 
    INNER JOIN @mstr M ON S.memberids = M.memberid
        AND S.fnames = M.fname
        AND S.lnames = M.lname 
    GROUP BY M.memberid
    )B
INNER JOIN @mstr M ON B.memberid = M.memberid AND B.dob = M.dob

UNION

SELECT M.memberid,M.fname,M.lname,M.dob
FROM (
    SELECT M.memberid, MIN(M.dob) dob
    FROM @src S 
    INNER JOIN @mstr M ON S.memberids = M.memberid
    AND (S.fnames IS NULL OR S.fnames = '')
    GROUP BY M.memberid
    )B
INNER JOIN @mstr M ON B.memberid = M.memberid AND B.dob = M.dob

UNION

SELECT C.smid  memberids, 'XX'+CAST ((convert(numeric(5,0),rand() * 10000) + 9999)AS VARCHAR(5)) fname, 
'ZZ'+CAST ((convert(numeric(5,0),rand() * 10000) + 9999)AS VARCHAR(5)) lnames, 
DATEADD(YY,-110, GETDATE()) dob
FROM
(
SELECT S.memberids smid,M.memberid mmid
FROM @src S 
LEFT JOIN @mstr M ON S.memberids = M.memberid
)C WHERE 
C.smid IS NOT NULL
AND C.mmid IS NULL
```